# Extract Enabled/Disabled dates from jQuery datepicker object on live website using Chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a website that's showing a simple jQuery date picker - https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ Currently, it shows the dates, some of them are ENABLED and some are DISABLED.

Is there a way to write a code in JavaScript (chrome console) that can extract the list of enabled/disabled dates?

I am able to get datepicker object from input with id "datepicker", and I am able to execute the below statement that gives me the currently selected date.

`$('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");`

NOTE: I am trying to extract dates from the live website, it's NOT my own code and I do NOT have access to any pre-existing list of array of dates from the console.

Comment: jquery-ui datepicker doesn't have an option to disable specific dates.  It has an option for min/max dates and has a `beforeShowDay` callback which allows the code to determine if a specific day (one day at a time) is enabled.   So 1) **be sure** it's jquery-ui datepicker and not one of the other 10,000 date pickers and 2) if it is, you can't get a "list" of disabled dates.  You could inspect the css of the datepicker, but that's only when it's displayed/open.  Or you could determine how the existing code determines which dates are disabled and hook into that.